# Why do Windows processes keep contacting outside?

Tags: windows

Not sure if this is the right forum for the question, but if not I trust I get pointed to the right direction :-)

Just for fun I installed Simplewall on a fresh Win10 Pro system. Immediately after enabling the rules, I noticed that several Windows services are contacting MS servers. I can understand that for example MS Defender will as it's checking for updates, but why does for example cleanmgr.exe try to do the same?

Can anyone point me to a resource that tells me exactly why each of these services and apps are doing this?

Comment: Most of it is windows Telemetry.

Comment: Thanks, that figures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering just to lift this off the Unanswered -queue.*

---

As Moab comments, the biggest culprit is indeed Windows Telemetry. I confirmed the answer with the help of online resources by analyzing what exactly is connecting where and why.